# in bash seeking a specific line to add at the end of that line.

Tags: bash

Using bash I go trough a file and if I find a specific line I want to add at the end of that line. 
I seek trough a config file for "AllowGroups" and I want to keep what is written but add at the end of it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please give examples of sample Input and expected output in code tags in your post please.

Comment: sline=$(grep -n "AllowGroups wheel" /etc/ssh/sshd_config |cut -f1 -d:)
sed "${sline},1 c\AllowGroups wheel rgroup" /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config_n

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48404423/edit) to include more information.  In particular, please move your current code from a comment, where it is hard to read, into the question.

Comment: Basically I seek the line AllowGroups, and I want to add the rgroup at the end of that line using sed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add `rgroup` to each `AllowGroup` line that also lists `wheel`.  If so, you only need `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(AllowGroups[^#]\+\bwheel\b\)/\1 rgroup/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config_n
```

Tested with GNU `sed` v4.4 — you may need more or fewer backslashes depending on your version of `sed`.

- The `s///` command is to replace text.
- `AllowGroups[^#]\+\bwheel\b` matches `AllowGroups wheel`, with optional whitespace or other non-comment characters (`[^#]`) between them.  The `\bwheel\b` matches `wheel` as a whole word, so skips, e.g., `wheelio` or `freewheel`.
- The `\( \)` saves the matched text into `\1`.
- The replacement text, `\1 rgroup`, adds `rgroup` onto whatever was matched, i.e., `AllowGroups`...`wheel`.

Comment: sline=$(grep -n "AllowGroups wheel" /etc/ssh/sshd_config |cut -f1 -d:)
getAllowGroup=$(grep "AllowGroups" /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
sed "${sline},1 c\ ${getAllowGroup} rgroup" /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config_n   -- work but I get a space before the line AllowGroups

Comment: Your solution also work but I want to add at the end of the line not the begining

Comment: @PatrickLavoie I'm not sure what you mean.  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48404423/edit) to include a sample of your input file, and what output you want?  Then I can change my answer to fit.  Thanks!